# How to get the total height of stacked bar chart in order to annotate a value above

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-chart

So I am trying to annotate the total sum above this whole stacked bar chart.

I managed to get the sum but not the total height of the stacked bar chart so therefore it looks something like this:

[image]

I know there are some related/similar posts but I can't figure out how to get the total height.

**Here is my code:**

```
athletes = pd.read_csv('athlete_events.csv')

#get just Romania as a country 
df=athletes.loc[athletes["Team"]=="Romania",:] 
df=df[df['Medal'].notna()]

#count medals for teams sports just once 
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Team', 'NOC',    'Games',    'Year', 'Season', 'City' ,  'Sport', 'Event', 'Medal'],keep='first')

# groupby Team and Medal and get the counts
dfg = df.groupby(['Sport', 'Medal']).Medal.count().reset_index(name='counts')

# pivot the dfg, which will enable to plot the bar
dfp = dfg.pivot(index='Sport', columns='Medal', values='counts')

# add a total column, which will allow dfp to be sorted
dfp['total'] = dfp.sum(axis=1)
dfp=dfp[['Bronze', 'Silver','Gold' ,'total']]

# sort dfp
dfp = dfp.sort_values('total', ascending=False)
dfp.head()

# plot the rows without the total column
ax = dfp.iloc[:, :3].plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(20, 6))



#customizing the bar plot

#rotate the labels by 45 degrees
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize='11.5')

# Remove axes splines
for s in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)

# Remove x,y Ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

# Add padding between axes and labels
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=5)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)

# Add x,y gridlines
ax.grid(b=True, color='grey', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)

plt.xlabel('Sport', fontweight='bold', color = 'orange', fontsize='18')
plt.ylabel('Medal Count', fontweight='bold', color = 'orange', fontsize='18', labelpad=25)


#legend size
ax.legend(prop={'size': 11})
rects = ax.patches

#annotate total values
for rect, label in zip(rects, dfp['total']):

    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height, label,
            ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

The dataset can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results.

Can anyone explain to me how to get the total height?

**Data Sample**

```
ID,Name,Sex,Age,Height,Weight,Team,NOC,Games,Year,Season,City,Sport,Event,Medal
1,A Dijiang,M,24.0,180.0,80.0,China,CHN,1992 Summer,1992,Summer,Barcelona,Basketball,Basketball Men's Basketball,
2,A Lamusi,M,23.0,170.0,60.0,China,CHN,2012 Summer,2012,Summer,London,Judo,Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight,
3,Gunnar Nielsen Aaby,M,24.0,,,Denmark,DEN,1920 Summer,1920,Summer,Antwerpen,Football,Football Men's Football,
4,Edgar Lindenau Aabye,M,34.0,,,Denmark/Sweden,DEN,1900 Summer,1900,Summer,Paris,Tug-Of-War,Tug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War,Gold
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1988 Winter,1988,Winter,Calgary,Speed Skating,Speed Skating Women's 500 metres,
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1988 Winter,1988,Winter,Calgary,Speed Skating,"Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Speed Skating,Speed Skating Women's 500 metres,
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Speed Skating,"Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Speed Skating,Speed Skating Women's 500 metres,
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands,NED,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Speed Skating,"Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres",
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,31.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,31.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 50 kilometres,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,31.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,31.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,33.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,33.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 30 kilometres,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,33.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit,
6,Per Knut Aaland,M,33.0,188.0,75.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay,
7,John Aalberg,M,31.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres,
7,John Aalberg,M,31.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 50 kilometres,
7,John Aalberg,M,31.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit,
7,John Aalberg,M,31.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay,
7,John Aalberg,M,33.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10 kilometres,
7,John Aalberg,M,33.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 30 kilometres,
7,John Aalberg,M,33.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 10/15 kilometres Pursuit,
7,John Aalberg,M,33.0,183.0,72.0,United States,USA,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 4 x 10 kilometres Relay,
8,"Cornelia ""Cor"" Aalten (-Strannood)",F,18.0,168.0,,Netherlands,NED,1932 Summer,1932,Summer,Los Angeles,Athletics,Athletics Women's 100 metres,
8,"Cornelia ""Cor"" Aalten (-Strannood)",F,18.0,168.0,,Netherlands,NED,1932 Summer,1932,Summer,Los Angeles,Athletics,Athletics Women's 4 x 100 metres Relay,
9,Antti Sami Aalto,M,26.0,186.0,96.0,Finland,FIN,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Ice Hockey,Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey,
10,"Einar Ferdinand ""Einari"" Aalto",M,26.0,,,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Swimming,Swimming Men's 400 metres Freestyle,
11,Jorma Ilmari Aalto,M,22.0,182.0,76.5,Finland,FIN,1980 Winter,1980,Winter,Lake Placid,Cross Country Skiing,Cross Country Skiing Men's 30 kilometres,
12,Jyri Tapani Aalto,M,31.0,172.0,70.0,Finland,FIN,2000 Summer,2000,Summer,Sydney,Badminton,Badminton Men's Singles,
13,Minna Maarit Aalto,F,30.0,159.0,55.5,Finland,FIN,1996 Summer,1996,Summer,Atlanta,Sailing,Sailing Women's Windsurfer,
13,Minna Maarit Aalto,F,34.0,159.0,55.5,Finland,FIN,2000 Summer,2000,Summer,Sydney,Sailing,Sailing Women's Windsurfer,
14,Pirjo Hannele Aalto (Mattila-),F,32.0,171.0,65.0,Finland,FIN,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Biathlon,Biathlon Women's 7.5 kilometres Sprint,
15,Arvo Ossian Aaltonen,M,22.0,,,Finland,FIN,1912 Summer,1912,Summer,Stockholm,Swimming,Swimming Men's 200 metres Breaststroke,
15,Arvo Ossian Aaltonen,M,22.0,,,Finland,FIN,1912 Summer,1912,Summer,Stockholm,Swimming,Swimming Men's 400 metres Breaststroke,
15,Arvo Ossian Aaltonen,M,30.0,,,Finland,FIN,1920 Summer,1920,Summer,Antwerpen,Swimming,Swimming Men's 200 metres Breaststroke,Bronze
15,Arvo Ossian Aaltonen,M,30.0,,,Finland,FIN,1920 Summer,1920,Summer,Antwerpen,Swimming,Swimming Men's 400 metres Breaststroke,Bronze
15,Arvo Ossian Aaltonen,M,34.0,,,Finland,FIN,1924 Summer,1924,Summer,Paris,Swimming,Swimming Men's 200 metres Breaststroke,
16,Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen,M,28.0,184.0,85.0,Finland,FIN,2014 Winter,2014,Winter,Sochi,Ice Hockey,Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey,Bronze
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Individual All-Around,Bronze
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Team All-Around,Gold
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Floor Exercise,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Horse Vault,Gold
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Parallel Bars,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Horizontal Bar,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Rings,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,28.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Pommelled Horse,Gold
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Individual All-Around,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Team All-Around,Bronze
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Floor Exercise,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Horse Vault,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Parallel Bars,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Horizontal Bar,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Rings,
17,Paavo Johannes Aaltonen,M,32.0,175.0,64.0,Finland,FIN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Pommelled Horse,
18,Timo Antero Aaltonen,M,31.0,189.0,130.0,Finland,FIN,2000 Summer,2000,Summer,Sydney,Athletics,Athletics Men's Shot Put,
19,Win Valdemar Aaltonen,M,54.0,,,Finland,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Art Competitions,"Art Competitions Mixed Sculpturing, Unknown Event",
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,20.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,20.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Super G,Gold
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,20.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Giant Slalom,Bronze
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,20.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1992 Winter,1992,Winter,Albertville,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,22.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill,Silver
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,22.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Super G,Bronze
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,22.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Giant Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,22.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,22.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1994 Winter,1994,Winter,Lillehammer,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Combined,Silver
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,26.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1998 Winter,1998,Winter,Nagano,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,26.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1998 Winter,1998,Winter,Nagano,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Super G,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,26.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1998 Winter,1998,Winter,Nagano,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Giant Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,26.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,1998 Winter,1998,Winter,Nagano,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Combined,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,30.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,30.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Super G,Gold
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,30.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Giant Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,30.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Slalom,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,30.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2002 Winter,2002,Winter,Salt Lake City,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Combined,Gold
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,34.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2006 Winter,2006,Winter,Torino,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill,
20,Kjetil Andr Aamodt,M,34.0,176.0,85.0,Norway,NOR,2006 Winter,2006,Winter,Torino,Alpine Skiing,Alpine Skiing Men's Super G,Gold
21,Ragnhild Margrethe Aamodt,F,27.0,163.0,,Norway,NOR,2008 Summer,2008,Summer,Beijing,Handball,Handball Women's Handball,Gold
22,Andreea Aanei,F,22.0,170.0,125.0,Romania,ROU,2016 Summer,2016,Summer,Rio de Janeiro,Weightlifting,Weightlifting Women's Super-Heavyweight,
23,Fritz Aanes,M,22.0,187.0,89.0,Norway,NOR,2000 Summer,2000,Summer,Sydney,Wrestling,"Wrestling Men's Light-Heavyweight, Greco-Roman",
23,Fritz Aanes,M,26.0,187.0,89.0,Norway,NOR,2004 Summer,2004,Summer,Athina,Wrestling,"Wrestling Men's Light-Heavyweight, Greco-Roman",
24,Nils Egil Aaness,M,24.0,,,Norway,NOR,1960 Winter,1960,Winter,Squaw Valley,Speed Skating,Speed Skating Men's 500 metres,
24,Nils Egil Aaness,M,24.0,,,Norway,NOR,1960 Winter,1960,Winter,Squaw Valley,Speed Skating,"Speed Skating Men's 1,500 metres",
24,Nils Egil Aaness,M,27.0,,,Norway,NOR,1964 Winter,1964,Winter,Innsbruck,Speed Skating,"Speed Skating Men's 1,500 metres",
25,Alf Lied Aanning,M,24.0,,,Norway,NOR,1920 Summer,1920,Summer,Antwerpen,Gymnastics,"Gymnastics Men's Team All-Around, Free System",Silver
26,Agnes Erika Aanonsen (-Eyde),F,17.0,169.0,65.0,Norway,NOR,1984 Winter,1984,Winter,Sarajevo,Luge,Luge Women's Singles,
27,Johan Aantjes,M,26.0,,,Netherlands,NED,1984 Summer,1984,Summer,Los Angeles,Water Polo,Water Polo Men's Water Polo,
28,Jan-Erik Aarberg,M,43.0,170.0,77.0,Norway,NOR,1968 Summer,1968,Summer,Mexico City,Sailing,Sailing Mixed Three Person Keelboat,
28,Jan-Erik Aarberg,M,47.0,170.0,77.0,Norway,NOR,1972 Summer,1972,Summer,Munich,Sailing,Sailing Mixed Three Person Keelboat,
29,Willemien Aardenburg,F,22.0,,,Netherlands,NED,1988 Summer,1988,Summer,Seoul,Hockey,Hockey Women's Hockey,Bronze
30,Pepijn Aardewijn,M,26.0,189.0,72.0,Netherlands,NED,1996 Summer,1996,Summer,Atlanta,Rowing,Rowing Men's Lightweight Double Sculls,Silver
30,Pepijn Aardewijn,M,30.0,189.0,72.0,Netherlands,NED,2000 Summer,2000,Summer,Sydney,Rowing,Rowing Men's Lightweight Double Sculls,
31,Evald rma (rman-),M,24.0,174.0,70.0,Estonia,EST,1936 Summer,1936,Summer,Berlin,Athletics,Athletics Men's Pole Vault,
32,Olav Augunson Aarnes,M,23.0,,,Norway,NOR,1912 Summer,1912,Summer,Stockholm,Athletics,Athletics Men's High Jump,
33,Mika Lauri Aarnikka,M,24.0,187.0,76.0,Finland,FIN,1992 Summer,1992,Summer,Barcelona,Sailing,Sailing Men's Two Person Dinghy,
33,Mika Lauri Aarnikka,M,28.0,187.0,76.0,Finland,FIN,1996 Summer,1996,Summer,Atlanta,Sailing,Sailing Men's Two Person Dinghy,
34,Jamale (Djamel-) Aarrass (Ahrass-),M,30.0,187.0,76.0,France,FRA,2012 Summer,2012,Summer,London,Athletics,"Athletics Men's 1,500 metres",
35,Dagfinn Sverre Aarskog,M,24.0,190.0,98.0,Norway,NOR,1998 Winter,1998,Winter,Nagano,Bobsleigh,Bobsleigh Men's Four,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the total value from your dataframe as the `y` position, instead of the height of the bar. Something like:

```
#annotate total values
for rect, total in zip(rects, dfp['total']):
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, total, total,
            ha='center', va='center')
```